# what is the most optimial way to convert Arraylist<Integer> to char[]

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I am wondering is there anyways probably by stream API to convert

```
List<Integer> li = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,45,678);
```

to `char[]` ch without going to an intermediate stage of `String`? I could not find one.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the solution , but i had to have a intermediate `String` Transformation.

```
List<Integer> li = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,45,678); 
        String Str =li.toString();
        char [] ch = new char[Str.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<Str.length();i++)
        {
         ch[i] =    Str.charAt(i);
        }
        for(char cc:ch)
        {        
            System.out.print(cc);
        }
```

> Output: [1, 2, 3, 45, 678]

Answer (score 4):

Possibly a way to iterate over the list and assign the values to respective index in the array as:

```
IntStream.range(0, li.size())
         .forEach(i -> ch[i] = (char) li.get(i).intValue());
```

or if primitives are not a must, then something like:

```
Character[] ch = li.stream()
                   .map(i -> (char) i.intValue())
                   .toArray(Character[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way is to declare an array of characters and save the list array in the char array by for loop and toArray() funtion.